# htaccess: RewriteRule, Tomcat & 503

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Given the following htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

If the Tomcat instance is running under Port 8080, the request will be passed.
If the instance is not running, I'm getting an ugly 503-error.

I was trying to replace it with a custom-made page. This works:

```
ErrorDocument 503 "offline"
```

but this doesn't:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /home/www-data/error/503.html
```

I'm getting:

```
Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ErrorDocument you need to give the path of your html page, relative to the document root. So if the DocumentRoot is `/home/www-data/` simply set `/error/503.html`.

Now if this is a `.htaccess` present in `/home/www-data/` then all documents which are children of this directories get the rules applied. So I think even your `/error/503.html` is treated by your Proxy directive:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Would be instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

I think it should be enough, or you can exclude `/error` from the matching path.